# Removing UIImageView On Touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm working on a project where images are spawned and you basically touch them and they are removed. How would I removed the object that I touched? I've thought of making a mutablearray to hold all the objects but i can't seem to figure anything out.

```
GameViewController.m

#import "GameViewController.h"
#import "Cig.h"

@interface GameViewController ()

@end

@implementation GameViewController
@synthesize scoreLbl, timeLbl;

//CLASS ONLY VARS
BOOL isGameOver;
int timeInt;
int scoreInt;
int cigsOnScreen;
NSMutableArray *spawnedCigs;
//CLASS ONLY VARS

//TIMER
-(void)count {
    timeInt--;
    timeLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Time: %i", timeInt];

    if(timeInt == 0){
        isGameOver = YES;
        NSLog(@"Your Score For This Round: %i", scoreInt);
    }

    if(isGameOver == NO){
        [self performSelector:@selector(count) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}
//TIMER

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)spawnCigs {
    for(int i =0 ; i < 5; i++){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(arc4random()%760, arc4random()%430, 100, 23)];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cig.png"];
        [imageView setImage:image];
        Cig *cig = [[Cig alloc] init];
        [cig setTag:arc4random()%666];
        [cig setImage:imageView];
        [spawnedCigs addObject:cig];
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(spawnCigs) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

-(void)reset {
    scoreLbl.text = @"Score:";
    timeLbl.text = @"Time:";
    isGameOver = NO;
    timeInt = 60;
    scoreInt = 0;
    cigsOnScreen = 0;
    spawnedCigs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil, nil];

    [self performSelector:@selector(count) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self reset];
    [self spawnCigs];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Code is pretty messy so please don't judge me on that.

Thanks for any help that is provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
  UITouch *touch=[[event allTouches]anyObject];
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view];;
  for (UIView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
  {
    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
    {
       if (CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame,touchPoint))
       {
         [view removeFromSuperview];
       }
    }
  }
}
```

this helps you

Comment: Thanks, I don't completely understand this but the others did help to understand this in the end. I combined 2 answers to get the results I wanted, thanks

Answer (score 1):

use

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
 for (UIImageView *view in [self.view subviews]) 
    {
        if (view.tag==1)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
        if (view.tag==2)
        {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

}
```

try this your issue will be resolved. Don't forget to pass tab to your imageviews...

Comment: Don't use code directly. try him to find out the solutions. Explain it how he can achieve with his own.

Comment: Thank you, I used this to find my solution

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
 -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method you will get the image view of selected image. simply remove the object from superview.